# Inhomogeneous Sturm-Liouville problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, sturm-liouville

For the following 3 similar Sturm-Liouville problems, I'm struggling to understand how to get to the solutions. I know the solutions already but wolfram alpha gives others, maybe more general ones. The 3 problems are:

(1) $$4y(x)=(x-4)y'(x)+(x^2-16x+55)y''(x)-5x-66, y(0)=26,y'(0)=-15$$
(2) $$4y(x)=(x-6)y'(x)+(x^2-17x+52)y''(x)+4x-52, y(0)=33,y'(0)=-14$$
(3) $$4y(x)=(x-8)y'(x)+(x^2-15x+54)y''(x)+10x-64, y(0)=35,y'(0)=-12$$

The solutions I know are:

(1') $$x^2-15x+26$$
(2') $$x^2-14x+33$$
(3') $$x^2-12x+35$$

Wolfram Alpha's answers may be found in the following:

[First Problem](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4y%28x%29%3D%28x-4%29*y%27%28x%29%2B%28x%5E2-16x%2B55%29*y%27%27%28x%29-5x-66%2Cy%280%29%3D26%2Cy%27%280%29%3D-15)

[Second Problem](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4y%28x%29%3D%28x-6%29*y%27%28x%29%2B%28x%5E2-17x%2B52%29*y%27%27%28x%29%2B4x-56%2Cy%280%29%3D33%2Cy%27%280%29%3D-14)

[Third Problem](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=4y%28x%29%3D%28x-8%29y%27%28x%29%2B%28x%5E2-15x%2B54%29*y%27%27%28x%29%2B10x-64%2Cy%280%29%3D35%2Cy%27%280%29%3D-12)

My question is: How to arrive at the solutions I know, and are wolfram alpha's solutions more general ones?

Answer (score 1):

Taking the first ode,

$$
\left(x^2-16 x+55\right) y''(x)+(x-4) y'(x)-4 y(x)-5 x-66=0
$$

assuming that the solution has the structure

$$
y = a x^2+b x + c
$$

after substitution we get

$$
2 (55 a-2 b-2 c-33)-x (40 a+3 b+5)=0\ \ \ \forall \ \ x
$$

then

$$
\cases{
55 a-2 b-2 c-33=0\\
40 a+3 b+5=0
}\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \Rightarrow \cases{a = \frac{1}{245}(6c+89)\\ b=-\frac{1}{49}(16c+319)}
$$

or

$$
y = \frac{1}{245} (6 c+89) x^2-\frac{1}{49} (16 c+319) x+c
$$

and this solution casually admits the two initial conditions but if the conditions were other, the free parameter $c$ at the solution, would not be enough to accept them. I think something similar happens in the other two cases.

Comment: I had observed this assumption too. Maybe I should have said it. Anyway this assumption is strong. Hopefully there is a simpler way than Wolfram Alpha does, but still not requiring prior knowledge about the solution!

Comment: Note that in the first ode, if we had instead of $y(0)=26,y'(0)=-15$ another conditions, as for instance $y(0)=26,y'(0) = -14$, this kind of polynomial solution will be unsatisfactory.

Comment: Noted! Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Doesn't that mean that this solution is discontious with the initial conditions making the problem ill posed? I also wander, given Wolfram alpha 's answer, if this solution is not unique, making the problem also I'll posed.

Comment: The polynomial solution is a particular solution which coincides with the general solution in those cases.